# double vertical bar as an alternative to increment operator

Tags: algorithm, increment

I am doing an assignment from MIT OCW,in the pseudocode of a naive division algorithm "||" is used as and faster version of increment operator ie(++), can anyone explain how this is supposed to work
here is the pseudocode with comments:

[image]

Comment: What is the type of `Q` here? What does `Q[0]` mean?

Comment: It multiplies Q by 2 in line 10 so Q[0] is even. For even numbers the least significant bit is set so `Q[0] | 1` is equivalent to adding 1. Though the author should have probably used a bitwise instead of a logical or (it's pseudocode but there are some common conventions). This is not faster than addition on any modern cpu.

Comment: You want us to tell you how someone's made-up language works?  Good luck with that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the author is referring to `bitwise OR` operator by `||`. Normally a bitwise operator is represented by `|` in many languages (e.g., java).

Before the line 13 `Q[0] = Q[0] || 1`, the last bit of `Q[0]` will always be `0`, because the value of `Q[0]` is doubled in line 10 and that makes `Q[0]` an even number. So if you do a bitwise or with `Q[0]` that sets the last bit of `Q[0]` to 1, which basically increase the value of `Q[0]` by 1.